# Inheriting ConstructorArguments in Ninject

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

I'm trying to find a method of passing a constructor argument to the constructors of child classes.
These objects are immutable so I'd prefer to use constructor arguments.

The issue I have encountered is that ConstructorArgument does not inherit to child instantiations and the following statements are not interchangeable:

```
_parsingProcessor = _kernel.Get<IParsingProcessor>(new ConstructorArgument("dataFilePath", dataFilePath);
```

and

```
_parsingProcessor = _kernel.Get<IParsingProcessor>(new Parameter("dataFilePath", dataFilePath, true);
```

So, how can get an inheritable ConstructorArgument and when does it makes sense, if ever, to new the Parameter class?

Comment: Can you give more information about what you are trying to do? It is possible to pass a parameter to a child. But in most scenarios this isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but it's probably not what you really want. If the container is not actually responsible for instantiating its own dependencies, then its dependencies *probably* shouldn't be sharing its constructor arguments - it just doesn't make sense.

I'm pretty sure I know what you're trying to do, and the recommended approach is to create a unique binding specifically for your one container, and use the `WhenInjectedInto` conditional binding syntax, as in the example below:

```
public class Hello : IHello
{
    private readonly string name;

    public Hello(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}!", name);
    }
}
```

This is the class that takes a constructor argument which we want to modify, depending on who is asking for an `IHello`.  Let's say it's this boring container class:

```
public class MyApp : IApp
{
    private readonly IHello hello;

    public MyApp(IHello hello)
    {
        this.hello = hello;
    }

    public virtual void Run()
    {
        hello.SayHello();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now, here's how you do up the bindings:

```
public class MainModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IApp>().To<MyApp>();
        Bind<IHello>().To<Hello>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("name", "Jim");
        Bind<IHello>().To<Hello>()
            .WhenInjectedInto<MyApp>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("name", "Bob");
    }
}
```

Basically all this binding is doing is saying the `name` should be "Jim" **unless** it's being requested by `Hello`, which in this case it is, so instead it will get the name "Bob".

---

If you are absolutely *certain* that you truly want cascading behaviour and understand that this is **very dangerous and brittle**, you can cheat using a method binding.  Assuming that we've now added a `name` argument to the `MyApp` class for some unspecified purpose, the binding would be:

```
Bind<IHello>().ToMethod(ctx =>
    ctx.Kernel.Get<Hello>(ctx.Request.ParentContext.Parameters
        .OfType<ConstructorArgument>()
        .Where(c => c.Name == "name")
        .First()));
```

Please, please, make sure you are *positive* that this is what you want before doing it. It looks easy but it is also very likely to break during a simple refactoring, and 95% of the "customized dependency" scenarios I've seen can be addressed using the `WhenInjectedInto` binding instead.